# Can't access My Swift classes into Objective-C application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode7

I have created an application in Objective-C. I wants to use My Classes written in Swift into application for this i have done following things

- set **Defines Module** to YES.
- Defined **Product Module Name**
  [image]

I created a swift file something like this **MyClass.swift**

```
import Foundation
class MyClass: NSObject
{
    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("SwiftClass init")
    }
}


@objc class SwiftClass : NSObject {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("SwiftClass init")
    }

    func sayHello() -> Void {
        print("hello");
    }

    func addX(x:Int, andY y:Int) -> Int {
        return x+y
    }

    // Make a dictionary
    // No, this code doesn't protect against values.count > keys.count
    func dictionaryWithKeys(keys:[String], andValues values:[String]) -> Dictionary<String,String> {

        var dictionary = Dictionary<String,String>()

        for var i = 0; i < keys.count; i++ {
            dictionary[keys[i]] = values[i]
        }

        return dictionary

    }

}
```

after **successfully Clean & Build** i have swift header file in my application named **Testing-Swift.h** as shown in pic -
[image]

I am able to import my header file in my **ViewController.m** but not able to access the classes written in swift - [image]

Please help me .I am using Xcode 7.2

Comment: Check your "Testing-Swift.h" file if your swift objects and methods are there. By the way, you don`t need to activate Modules to use Swift in your project.

Comment: Dear LoVo ,I have separate "MyClass.swift" file , all the classes & methods are here.  as shown above .

Comment: Ok, in that case just remove the swift classes code from the objective c class, compile and try again to use the swift objects in obj-c class.

Comment: did , still same issue .

Answer (score 0):

Click on your Xcode Project file,click on Build Setting,find a search bar and Search "Defines module" and tick out "Yes".
After search "PRODUCT MODULE,write Your Project name,rewrite in Your App delegates #Import "YourProjectName-swift.h"